# limit statement in Hadoop Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Wondering if I add limit to any Pig statement, it will always improve performance? Any anti-case, when adding limit statement will not improve performance, but drop?

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **limit operator** in Pig used to limit the number of output results to print over Shell or save it to file.

This operator is always can yield a much better performance as we push the limit as high as possible to minimise the amount of data travelling through the pipeline.

Limit is an **optimisation technique** in **Pig**. So it always provides **better performance**. I don't think so any negative effect of this Operator.

It is always have significant performance benefits.